# System resources process questions

Tags: command-line, process, top

Is there a way you can find the percentage of CPU time used by a process on the command line?

Also I want to find out what the cpu time is by a certain process as well as the percentage of memory that that process is using by using the command line.

Comment: have you tried the command `top`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the process ID (pid), then you can run:

```
top -p <pid1>,<pid2>...
```

And to get the list of process IDs for a given process name you can use:

```
pgrep <process-name>
```